# To convert GNU paste to BSD

Tags: text

Command in GNU

```
echo "Masi,hello" | paste -sd,
```

which I want in BSD paste. 
I am reading this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209789/16920).

How can you write this in BSD paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On OSX you'll have to add an extra "-"

```
echo "Masi,hello" | paste -sd, -
```